# react-native: notify server that user logged into Facebook oAuth

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

So this is probably a thing I am missing.... I am building a react-native app for IOS, using facebook SDK for Facebook login (react-native-fbsdk). 
it all works fine.... but, I want the app to access my server, and my server needs to know that the user is logged in (and who the user is).

I know how to do it with the standard oAuth server flow, but how do I do it in this case? how do I even get the code or access token?
In the FB documentation all I see is how to make requests from the app to FB API, I didn't find where to have a callback on the server, so that I can setup the session cookie with user info.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LoginButton` and set the required permissions. It will return you the access token, that you can send to your server. The server gets the username, email etc. via this access token from the facebook oauth service. Then the server can open the session and send the session id back to your react native app.

```
        <LoginButton
            readPermissions={["email", "public_profile"]}
            onLoginFinished={
              (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  //alert("login has error: " + result.error);
                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                  // cancelled
                } else {
                  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                    (data) => {
                      console.log("acces token:", data);
                      const token = data.accessToken.toString();
                      // call your server
                      // server can get user info from facebook
                      // returns back the session id
                    }
                  )
                }
              }
            }
            onLogoutFinished={() => true}/>
```

Comment: thanks man, a life saver. After i send the token to the server, i validate by calling Facebook api (some '.../me) and with simply the knowledge of the access token I should be able to get the name and email, etc, is that so?

Comment: if you are using php here is an example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile